# Pivoting dataframe to create a heatmap?

Tags: r

I have a `df` that looks like this, where the Drug variables are binary and the Score variable is continuous (ordinal):

```r
df <- structure(list(Drug1 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
               Drug2 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
               Drug3 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), 
               Score = c(2L, 4L, 0L, 6L)), 
          class = "data.frame",
          row.names = c(NA,-4L))
```

I would like to create a heatmap--something akin to this, but I want the drugs to be represented in the columns and the `Score` variable to be represented in the row:
[image]

Heatmap [photo source](https://r-graph-gallery.com/215-the-heatmap-function.html)

Comment: Try: `heatmap(as.matrix(d))`

Answer (score 2):

With the base R `heatmap()`:

```
rownames(d)<-d$Score          # give rownames based on score

# set the color scheme for the heatmap
colors <- colorRampPalette(c("yellow", "red"))(2)

# plot heatmap
heatmap(as.matrix(d[,1:3])
        ,col=colors
        ,cexRow = 1      #text size of rows
        ,cexCol = 1      #text size of columns
        ,Colv = NA       # not show column dendrogram (not order)
        ,Rowv = NA       # same as Colv but for rows
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Score, names_to = "Drug") %>%
  ggplot(aes(Drug, Score, fill = value)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "YlOrRd")
```

[image]